# Scala How to flatten nested Map[String, Any]

Tags: scala

I have nested map as below:

```
val x: Map[String, Any] = 
  Map("a" -> "apple", "b" -> "ball", "c" -> Map("x" -> "cat", "y" -> 12))
```

and I want to convert it into:

```
Map("a" -> "apple", "b" -> "ball", "x" -> "cat", "y" -> 12)
```

However, if I try to invoke flatten to x then I get exception.

```
x.flatten
Error:(40, 14) No implicit view available from (String, Any) => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
println(mx.flatten)
Error:(40, 14) not enough arguments for method flatten: (implicit asTraversable: ((String, Any)) => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[B].
Unspecified value parameter asTraversable.
println(x.flatten)
```

So, how can I provide implicit view in order to flatten the above map?

Comment: Have a look here: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-combine-map-flatten-flatmap-scala-cookbook I think flatten is the wrong approach.

Comment: What if `x` is already a key on the outer map?

Comment: Why do you have that data structure in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit strange you want to loose the information about 'c'.
But anyway, the compiler is complaining because it does not know how to convert the (String,Any), your Key -> Value pair into a traversable and that is logical.
You could provide the compiler with a hint that in case the 'Any' is a Map, it should only use the values and loose the key.

For example:

```
x.flatten {
  case ((key, map : Map[String, Any])) => map
  case ((key, value)) => Map(key -> value)
}.toMap
```

This returns

```
Map(a -> apple, b -> ball, x -> cat, y -> 12)
```

Note: the 'toMap' is needed because the 'flatten' returns a List[(String,Any)].

Comment: Thank you, this is really what I needed.