# Deep flatten Scala Maps (or uJson Objs) - how to?

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, flatmap, ujson

**How can I flatten deep nested Maps in Scala returning a new map with the relevant nested key in dot notation?**

*Background: I am trying to do so for `uJson.Obj`s, but since they are just `mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, Value]` under-the-hoods, answers for standard library maps should help as well.*

For example:

```
   val original = Obj("Simple" -> "a",
        "nested" ->
          Obj("c1" ->
            Obj("c2" -> "a")))
   
   flattenObj(original) shouldEqual Obj("simple" -> "a", "nested.c1.c2" -> "a")
```

I have tried the following (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277057/scala-how-to-flatten-nested-mapstring-any)), but it works only for the first level, and still don't deal with naming new keys in dot notation:

```
    def flattenObj(o: Obj, delimiter: String = "."): Obj = {
      o.obj.flatMap {
        case (key, map: Obj) => map.obj
        case (key, value) => Map(key -> value)
      }
    }
```

It results in:

```
Actual: {"Simple":"a","c1":{"c2":"a"}}
```

But, I expect:

```
Expected: {"simple":"a","nested.c1.c2":"a"}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: for one, your solution should be recursive. Something along the lines of ```def flattenObj(o: Obj, delimiter: String = ".", keyAcc: String=""): Obj = {
      o.obj.flatMap {
        case (key, map: Obj) => flattenObj(map.obj, keyAcc = keyAcc + "." + key)
        case (key, value) => Map(keyAcc + "." + key -> value)
      }
    }```

Comment: Thanks, @Raf. Please add implemented based on your guidance and worked fine. I will post and answer with the final implementation to help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Final implementation based on the @Raf's guidance in the comments:

```
  def flattenObj(o: Obj, keyAcc: String = "", delimiter: String = "."): Obj = {
    o.obj.flatMap(kv => {
      val key: String = if (keyAcc.isEmpty) kv._1 else keyAcc + delimiter + kv._1

      kv._2 match {
        case map: Obj => flattenObj(map.obj, key, delimiter).obj
        case value => Map(key -> value)

      }
    })
  }
```

Thank you [Raf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088380/raf).